# Non Repetitive, Left Mouse Click in a Loop

Tags: loops, while-loop, mouseevent

I am new to Python and these forums, so please bear with me and any help is appreciated.

I did search the Stack Overflow forums for this question and located a post on the topic. However, that post seemed to look for mouse location coordinates in multiple windows and to have a single output of those coordinates with a single click, which is not what I need.

I am building a game bot program as a means of learning python. I need a single left click to occur as a means of targeting the enemy and this needs to happen once, each time the program loops.

This is the code I am using to cause the left click and have created a definition for "click" (see larger block of code below):

```
#TARGET ENEMY
if pyautogui.pixel (1096,127) [0] == 16:
        click(1096,127)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

When I place this code in the loop, I get repeated left mouse clicks for the entire duration of the program and when I set it out side the loop, it plays just once and then never plays again unless I stop and restart the program.

I cant seem to figure out/find a counter code or function in pyautogui that will play the left mouse click once and move on to the next section of the loop. I have also tried to reorganize the code in various configurations and none of it seems to help the problem. I am confident I need code to tell it to move down the loop after one left mouse click.

I don't see a "duration" or "click counter" type of function

Here is the entire code block

```
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    time.sleep(0.9)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0) 

def debuff(key):
    pyautogui.keyDown("4")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pyautogui.keyUp("4")

def attack1(key):
    pyautogui.keyDown("8")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pyautogui.keyUp("8")
    time.sleep(0.9)    

def attack2(key):
    pyautogui.keyDown("2")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pyautogui.keyUp("2")
    time.sleep(0.9)
    
def attack3(key):
    pyautogui.keyDown("1")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pyautogui.keyUp("1")
    time.sleep(0.7)

#TARGET ENEMY
if pyautogui.pixel (1096,127) [0] == 16:
        click(1096,127)
        time.sleep(0.5)

#Used to stop the programq
while keyboard.is_pressed('g') == False:
     
        #DEBUFF
    if pyautogui.pixel (1127, 1268) [0] == 247:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        curse("4")
        time.sleep(3)
                
        #ATTACK1          
    if pyautogui.pixel (1517, 1269) [0] == 247:
        lifedrain("8")
        time.sleep(3)

         #ATTACK2
            #if pyautogui.pixel (954, 1263) [0] == 244:
                #swarm("2")
                #time.sleep(0.9)

        #ATTACK 3
    if pyautogui.pixel (1096,127) [0] == 16:
            poke("1")
```